# How do I assign an initial value to a dynamic variable without using assignment operator?

Tags: c++, initialization, new-operator

I am creating a dynamic variable in the heap via a pointer.

```
int* p = new int;
```

I'm sure we're all familiar with that. However, I want to create the dynamic variable and give it an initial value *all in one step*!
I do not want to later use the assignment operator.

```
*p = 5;
```

I want all of my dynamic variables to have the same initial value, avoiding the extra overhead of the assignment operator.

How would you do this if the dynamic variable were a class instead of an int? I know that it's possible to create and initialize a class variable of the stack in one step:

```
class Dog {...};

Dog d1("Spot", 5);
```

Can you do the same if the `Dog` object were a dynamic one instead?
My program needs to dynamically allocate and initialize variables of both POD and class types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) supports it. Just specify the initializer.

> initialization of an object with dynamic storage duration by a new-expression with a non-empty initializer

```
int* p = new int(5);
Dog* d1 = new Dog("Spot", 5);
```

Comment: Neat! I didn't know you could do that!